# Add 2 UIViews to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Is it possible to use `UIScrollViewController` to scroll or "page" two or more views coming from `UIViewControllers`?
Example (in viewDidLoad)

```
        self.a1    = [[CustomViewController1 alloc] init];

        self.a2  = [[CustomViewController2 alloc] init];

        //Scroller
        self.scroller   = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1000,400
                                                                        400)];
        [self.scroller addSubview:self.a1.view];
        [self.scroller addSubview:self.a2.view];

        [self.view addSubview:self.scroller];
```

But I can see in the scroller only the view of controller a2.

Comment: try to setContentSize for scrollview

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the frames of the views so they they sit one below another. Currently they are both there, just on top of one another.

Try putting in

```
self.a2.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 480);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the frames aswell. Now a1 and a2 have the same, and they are on top of eachother, so the a2 is visible, because you added the later.

Try

```
self.a2.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.a2.view.frame, self.a1.view.frame.size.width, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set the frame coordinates of the subviews inside the scroller:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 600);
self.a1    = [[CustomViewController1 alloc] init];
self.a1.view.frame = frame;

self.a2  = [[CustomViewController2 alloc] init];
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width +10;
self.a2.view.frame = frame;
[self.scroller addSubview:self.a1.view];
[self.scroller addSubview:self.a2.view];

[self.view addSubview:self.scroller];
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the custom view controllers as child view controllers. See [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) for more information on doing that correctly.